# Computer hangs at Checking NSS Setup after trying to run sudo dpkg configure a

Tags: boot, grub2, dpkg

I have looked up several different searches that would answer my question, and no one else has seemed to have this problem. The problem is as follows:

I was updating my Ubuntu version to 17.04 and while at it, my laptop ended up freezing. I had to shut it down by holding the button. When I started it back up, it would load until it reached the blue "Ubuntu" loading screen, and would then show a black screen. As soon as my mouse cursor shows up, my screen starts flashing/blinking on and off, going from off to a black screen to off and back on again. When I start up the "Recovery Mode" by going in GRUB, I tried a lot of things, and eventually I found out that I had to run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, but by doing this, it just hangs when it reaches "Checking NSS Setup", and does not go further.

I can't find a solution anywhere else, So this is where I am turning to. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am borrowing my dad's laptop to post this question, and I have no other way to get online.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue, I re-installed Ubuntu from a .iso CD.

It recognized the installation as 17.04 and gave me the option to overwrite it.